# Published Modules is disabled in Artifactory (using Jenkins Artifactory plugin)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

We have successfully our deployed artifacts with Jenkins - Artifactory plugin, however we cannot see them in Artifacts => Builds => Published Modules tab.

[image: Jenkins Artifactory configuration]

We can see the link as below:

[image: Published Modules]

If we click onto this link, the upcoming screen is completely disabled and empty.

[image: Published Modules-2]

Shouldn't we have the downloadable link of our deployed artifacts in this final screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Opensource version of Artifactory, which only allows browsing the buildInfo JSON file, not the Build Browser tabs.
You can replace the artifactory.war file to a pro version one (free 30 days trial), restart Artifactory and see all the information in the tabs.